# Unpacking a filter object

Tags: python, nlp

I am taking NLP course and trying to understand the codes provided in the book. I am trying to run it with Python 3 in Jupyter and got the unexpected result which is a list of objects, instead of the list of tokens filtered as in the book. I know that the author was using Python 2 so it may be the reason and there must be some ways to make the codes work in Python 3. I have tried to print it with list(), but it was still giving out same result. Below are the codes:

```
def remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens):
        pattern = re.compile('[{}]'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation)))
        filtered_tokens = filter(None, [pattern.sub('', token) for token in tokens]) 
        return filtered_tokens 

       filtered_list_1 =  [filter(None,[remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens) for tokens 
       in sentence_tokens]) for sentence_tokens in token_list]
       print(filtered_list_1)

       [<filter object at 0x7fb28c08fb20>, <filter object at 0x7fb28c08faf0>, <filter object at 
       0x7fb28c303910>]
```

And this is the expected token list:

```
[[['The', 'brown', 'fox', 'was', 'nt', 'that', 'quick', 'and', 'he',
     'could', 'nt', 'win', 'the', 'race']], [['Hey', 'that', 's', 'a', 'great',
     'deal'], ['I', 'just', 'bought', 'a', 'phone', 'for', '199']], [['You',
     'll', 'learn', 'a', 'lot', 'in', 'the', 'book'], ['Python', 'is', 'an',
     'amazing', 'language']]]
```

Could anyone help me with the issue? I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this line;

```
filtered_list_1 =  [filter(None,[remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens) for tokens 
   in sentence_tokens]) for sentence_tokens in token_list]
```

to:

```
filtered_list_1 =  [list(filter(None,[remove_characters_after_tokenization(tokens) for tokens 
   in sentence_tokens])) for sentence_tokens in token_list]
```

Comment: I tried but still resulted in objects as above.